# pfSense security: is the host of a virtual pfSense firewall accessible via ssh when the network interface has been assigned to pfSense?

Tags: virtualization, pfsense

Can the host of a virtual pfSense machine be accessed (via ssh) when the WAN interface is assigned to pfSense?

Would the drivers need to be installed on the host, guest or both?

Would it respond to a ping at all?
If yes, how can access to the host be disabled so that all traffic has to go through the firewall?

Comment: Based on your previous question, are you using Xen as your hypervisor?

Comment: It's a new linux server and has not been set up yet. Considering either Proxmox or using a linux host with libvirt / kvm / virt-manager. I haven't considered Xen as I need to run a few linux containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will absolutely depend on the configuration of the host machine, and the hypervisor in question.

As an example, here's the Hyper-V Virtual Network Manager panel, showing the relevant options:
[image: Hyper-V Virtual Network Manager]

By unchecking the **Allow management operating system to share this network adapter** (in the red box), and connecting the host OS to the internet via a virtual NIC connected to the pfSense VM internally (shown in the image as **PT-Internal**), you will fulfil the requirements in the question.

If the option is Enabled, the host will be available for access on that adapter, as normal.

The Hypervisor or host operating-system would need to support the NIC, and have appropriate drivers.

This setting will vary depending on the hypervisor, but is possible in most.

Comment: I realise, based on your comment about SSHing to the host, that it's somewhat unlikely (though not impossible) to be a Hyper-V host. Two moments, while I find the setting name for other hypervisors.